# Sharepoint 2013, cascading lookup/dropdown what happens with old data if data changes

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, dropdown, cascading

Situations tend to change, so sometimes cascading dropdown menu's get adapted because they are no longer relevant ...

My question is: what happens with metadata based on the old cascading dropdown list.

Example:
You used to have 20 tax offices all over the country, so you could choose: 
VAT-office (small enterprises) and afterwards office "Old location".
In "Old Location" they had meetings and metadata for the report, request location ...
However, at this moment you hav only 19 locations for VAT-office (small enterprises) and there is no more office at "Old location", so this item was unlinked, but still exists in the list linked to the item old location in stead of Vat-office ...

What happens to this information?
Does this item lose metadata
Can you still save changes to the item with the old metadata?